# check if table array value in range

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have  a table where one of the column contains surfaces like text: "200 300 450 557"
The user searches for surfaces giving a range that i get with 2 variables $min and $max.
I need to select all the properties that have surface in that interval.

Here i have the long solution but i believe there is a shorter one just within the select...

```
$min=$_GET["min"]; // min price given by user - like 1000 euro
$max=$_GET["max"]; // max price given by user - like 2500 euro

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `offers`");

$nr=mysql_numrows($result);
while( $i<$nr) {
    $surface=mysql_result($result,$i,"surface"); // something like "100 200 250 350" sqm
    $price=mysql_result($result,$i,"price"); // this is per square metter like "12" euro/sqm
    $s=explode(' ',$surface);

    if ($s[$i]*$price<=$max && $s[$i]*$price>=$min) // i don't know if it sees it like number or char???
    {
        $id = mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
        $area = mysql_result($result,$i,"area");
        $details = = mysql_result($result,$i,"det");

        // do something with them

    };
}
```

The point is that i need the simplest solution for multiple search.
If i would have a single surface the code wold be like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM `offers` WHERE (surface between $min and $max) && (price between $pmin and $pmax)&&(area='$area') ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 50;"
```

But if i have surface like "123 300 500 790..." what do i do? Is it possible in just one select?

Thanks

Comment: Can you split the surface sizes into their own table and have a many-to-many (or even a one-to-many) link? That design isn't too great.

Comment: plz stop using `mysql_*` since it has been deprecated... Start using `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

Comment: could be too many... how many columns should i have for each property 10...20 ..30? I prefer working with just one table and with arrays if posible

Comment: You really should redesign your table with proper normalization. Compensating for a bad design using even worse code is not a solution.

Comment: I don't want to make separate table for surfaces... and one for prices, and another for photos and one for tenants. There should be a solution to work with one table and with those values in arrays

Answer (score 0):

Use [min](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) and [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) for your array

```
if((min($s) * $price) >= $min && (max($s) * $price) <= $max)
{
    $id = mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
    $area = mysql_result($result,$i,"area");
    $details = = mysql_result($result,$i,"det");

    // do something with them
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use min/max in your query ? Like this: (untested)

```
$min=$_GET["min"]; // min price given by user - like 1000 euro
$max=$_GET["max"]; // max price given by user - like 2500 euro

// select from offers where price > min and price < max
$result=mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM `offers` WHERE `price` > %d AND `price` < %d",
    mysql_real_escape_string($min),
    mysql_real_escape_string($max)
));

$offers=mysql_numrows($result);

// loop over the offers
foreach($offers as $offer){
    $id = $offer['id'];
    $price = $offer['price'];

    // do something 
}
```

Now keep in mind that `mysql_query()` is deprecated. I recommend doing a PDO tutorial.

PDO tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Comment: thanks...i'll study than. Meanwhile i made some clarifications to the question.